# Redirect example.com/index to exmple.com

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

Due to a mistake in an article, one of our links was added as `example.com/index` instead of `example.com/index.html` or simply `example.com`. We have no access to the article nor possibility to change the link at this moment.

I was thinking to add a `.htaccess` rule and redirect `http://example.com/index` to `http://example.com`. I found solutions for redirecting subdirectories and files but cannot find a simple solution that works only for `http://example.com/index` (and not as a complete subdirectory) some other solutions failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If requesting `/index` is wrong it should result in a page not found. So see how this works for you in your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ / [R=301,L]
```